# Cannot get props from mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Been reading through Redux tutorials and a bit new to Redux. I am trying to access the current state that I have in my Redux Store. I can see the state object with my data in Redux State in dev tools but when I go to connect mapStateToProps the state returns undefined.

```
export class VersionDiff extends Component {
  render() {
    const { diffs } = this.props;
    console.log(diffs, 'im the diffs');
    return (
      <div>
        Empty Div
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    diffs: state.diffs,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(VersionDiff);
```

The console log I have in the render method returns undefined when I thought I could access the items from my redux store on this.props in the render method. This is my reducer below.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DIFFS':
      return [...state, action.diffs];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When I look at Redux devtools I can see the diffs object which I am trying to pull from the store. Im sure this is something very simple but just cannot seem to access this. 
[image]

Comment: The code currently in your question looks good to me. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: It looks to me like your reducer is expecting the state to be an array, but then your view is trying to extract a `diffs` object property from it?

Comment: That is a good point but I still should be able to get access to the props by the following console.log(this.props.diffs) I thought?

Comment: What does `console.log( this.props )` say?

Comment: I do get props back but without the state that I've dispatched to the store. I get something like the following 
`{location: {…}, params: {…}, route: {…}, router: {…}, routeParams: {…}, …}
children: null
location: {pathname: "/diffs", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, action: "POP", …}
params:{}route:{path: "/diffs", component: ƒ}
routeParams:{}
router:{getCurrentLocation: ƒ, listenBefore: ƒ, listen: ƒ, transitionTo: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
routes:(2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__:`

Comment: Figured this one out. What had happened was in my Routes.js file I was exporting my component as default but destructing the name as if it was a named export. Once I removed the braces from the name the store was available in this.props.diffs

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments, even if it's your own question. Post the solution as an answer and accept it. That way the question will show up as answered and the solution is clearly visible (as opposed to buried in the comment section).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try and provide some more clarity in case this might be helpful to anyone in the future. I believe what was happening here was since I am exporting my module as default in my connect function at the bottom of the file I would be able to use the standard import syntax. I believe I was trying to import my VersionDiff module as a named import so something like the following.

```
import { VersionDiff } from '../components/VersionDiff;
```

This wouldn't work as I was not able to access my component as it's a default export and therefore my props wouldn't be available to be passed into my component as the component would return undefined.

I believe this was a mistake on my end of not actually being able to find the component in my file before adding it into the connect function and try to pull state from the store.

Solution:

```
import VersionDiff from '../components/VersionDiff';
```